# React functional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, mixins

Let me show you an example first:

```js
<List hidden={this.state.hideList} />
```

For this case I would like `hidden` prop to function in the following way: if value is true – hide component or show otherwise. And `List` shouldn't be aware about this prop.

I don't know much about React internals, but it seems to be possible. We just need to extended `React.Component` class. Maybe extending globally with all functional props isn't good idea, but having something like this at the top would be nice:

```js
import { ReactComponent } from 'react'
import extend, { hidden } from 'react-functional-props'
const Component = extend(ReactComponent, hidden)
```

It reminds me directives in Angular.js, but here we are able to combine them.

Comment: `!this.state.hideList && <List />`?

Comment: More like directives in angular and vue, but doesn't React deliberately avoid such trappings in favor of conditional rendering.?

Comment: You could create such a mechanism that would hook un React.Component constructor or state paradigm and as soon as a specific property, say hidden, is changed to react in a generic way. A decorator, or a muxin, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can just return `null` or `undefined` in the render method to prevent it from rendering, or use a conditional class to hide it, like this:

```
return !this.state.hideList && <List />;
```

And about the

> react-functional-props

In React, you can use higher order component (HOC) to achieve what you need, for example:

```
const Hideable = Component => (props) => {
  const { isHidden, ...otherProps } = props;

  return !isHidden && (<Component {...otherProps} />);
};

const HideableList = Hideable(List);

...

return (
  <div>
    <HideableList isHidden={this.state.hideList} /> // The isHidden props is handled by the HOC
  </div>
);
```

But for a simple use case like this, I think just handle the hide and show in the parent component is much more clearer.